# i have error while create CRM app

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    AuthenticationResult authResult;
    private OrganizationDataWebServiceProxy proxy;
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myButton.Clicked += MyButton_Clicked;

        proxy = new OrganizationDataWebServiceProxy();
    }
    async void MyButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            var auth = DependencyService.Get&amp;lt;IAuthenticator&amp;gt;();
           authResult = await auth.Authenticate(Constants.Authority,

            Constants.ServiceURL,

            Constants.ClientId,

            Constants.RedirectURL,

            Constants.Username,

            Constants.Password);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            await DisplayAlert("Error", "This: " + ex, "got it");
        }

        proxy.ServiceUrl = Constants.ServiceURL;

        proxy.AccessToken = authResult.AccessToken;

        await GetLoggedInUserName();

    }
    public async Task GetLoggedInUserName()
    {
        try
        {
            WhoAmIResponse result = (WhoAmIResponse)await proxy.Execute(new WhoAmIRequest());

            await DisplayAlert("Result \n", "User Id : " + result.UserId.ToString() + "\n OrganizationId: " + result.OrganizationId.ToString() + "\n BusinessUnitId: " + result.BusinessUnitId.ToString(), "Ok", "Cancel");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            await DisplayAlert("Error", "This: " + ex, "got it");
        }
    }

}
```

}

And i get this error message

1.The name lt doesnt exist in the current text

2.The name amp doesnt exist in the current text

3.The name gt doesnt exist in the current text

4.IAuthenticator is a type which isnt valid in the given context

 somebody please help me, i was about to make crm app with xamarin.forms from this tutorial http://scaleablesolutions.com/connecting-xamarin-form-application-with-dynamics-crm/

Comment: Your copy-paste changed the characters, so the compiler does not recognice them. Change `DependencyService.Get&amp;lt;IAuthenticator&amp;gt;();` to `DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticator>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of that tutorial has some errors in code due to HTML encoding, and you copied that error.

Change line

```
var auth = DependencyService.Get&amp;lt;IAuthenticator&amp;gt;();
```

Into

```
var auth = DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticator>();
```

Comment: In case you wonder what is that `<IAuthenticator>`, you can check the doc about Generics https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang I would suggest marking the answer it as useful

Comment: and now i have more error from Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Samples and the error message is "the decompression method could not be found in the namespace system.net this type has been forwarded to assembly 'system.netprimiteve................'"

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang have you added reference to `Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples`

Comment: yes i already did that, and the error is in the microsoft,crm.sdk sample not in my code, i dont know what should i do

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang sorry, can't help you there. Try to ask new question here on SO with exception details